# Sys.time() in R

Tags: r, time

So this isn't so much a coding question, but an understanding of this function within `R`. 
Lets pretend that I am subtracting a known data and time from just a date with unknown time.
What is the default time `Sys.time()` uses in `R`?

example: endpoint (known time and date) - startpoint (known date)

The reason I ask is that I have a code, which I have been using. If it is a few hours off in every point, it won't make any difference in my data, but I want to know for myself.

Comment: Did you look at `?Sys.time`?

Comment: Can you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)? What are the classes of your `startpoint` and `endpoint` variables?

Comment: Is your known date an object of the `Date` class? If so you could execute e.g. `Sys.time()-(Sys.Date()-1)` and see the warning message.

Comment: @GSee, that was the first thing I did and cant find anything that makes sense to me, and @ shadow sure endpoint<- "2014-10-09 09:28:06 CDT", startpoint <- "2014-09-23 CDT"; thus, "2014-10-09 09:28:06 - "2014-09-23 CDT" = 363 hours

Comment: @nrussell this is what I was trying to find, it appears to use 5:19am CDT for unknown times

Comment: From `?as.POSIXct` - _"Dates without times are treated as being at midnight UTC"_

Comment: @ hrbrmstr, this can cant be. look up a few lines and you will see that what your wrote cant be what my answer is.